# Adding milliseconds to a date and get the new date by JavaScript

Tags: javascript, date

I want first Sunday of a year. I can fetch 1st day of year and add the remaining days for first Sunday (say for 2 days for year 2016) and now want the new date by adding milliseconds for thsoe 2 days. But I am not getting desired result. Please, help.

```
<script> 

    //I want to get date for 1st Sunday of Year
    var year = 2016;
    var date = new Date(year,0,1);
    var day = date.getDay();

    var dayDifference = ((7 - day)%7);
    var firstSunday = date.getMilliseconds() + (dayDifference * 86400000);

    console.log(new Date(firstSunday));

</script>
```

**RESULT:**

> Sat Jan 03 1970 05:30:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)

I expect date to be of 03 Jan 2016

Comment: Try `console.log( date.getMilliseconds() )`. What you're looking for is `date.getTime()`, or actually `date.setDate()` if you want to [do it correctly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/563406/add-days-to-javascript-date).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simple use `setDate` method to get desired result.

```
var year = 2016;
var date = new Date(year,0,1);
var day = date.getDay();

var dayDifference = ((7 - day)%7);
date.setDate(date.getDate() + dayDifference)
```

Answer (score 3):

Try This

```js
var year = 2016;
var date = new Date(year, 0, 1);
var day = date.getDay();

var dayDifference = ((7 - day) % 7);
var firstSunday = date.getTime() + (dayDifference * 86400000);

console.log(new Date(firstSunday));
```